# Net::SFTP keeps throwing errors in resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque, net-ssh, net-sftp

I am running rails 3.1rc4 and keep running into this error message in my resque queues

`uninitialized constant Net::SFTP` With the exception "NameError"

In my gemfile I have included:

```
gem 'net-sftp'
gem 'net-ssh'
gem 'net-scp'
```

I included net-scp, just in case it was a dependency. I have tested my resque task externally of rails and redis with straight ruby, in which I required 'net/ssh' and 'net/sftp'.  The whole thing worked perfectly.  However the same resque task continually throws the `uninitialized constant Net::SFTP`.  When I comment out the sftp section that comes before the Net::SSH section, I end up getting a similar error.

`uninitialized constant Net::SSH`

Do I need to change something in my gemfile or require these gems in my resque class? Why do I have to use 'net/ssh' in ruby while I have to use 'net-ssh' in my gemfile in rails?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded the environment in your rake task?

```
task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  # you can leave this blank
end
```

Resque, by default, runs standalone.  If you need it to access things that are loaded by the app bundle, you need to load the environment.